# API load testing with 10k users and I am choosing jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have requirement of test api with 10k users. What I choose is :

1. Jmeter
2. Linux server to install Jmeter and throw load with 10k users
3. One node for now

Will perform API with operations like :

- Login
- Book hotel with post parameters
- Update Booking Details
- Save Booking

I am thinking to use above for API testing with 10k users, Above tools are enough or I should look for other options like loadimpact, loader or blazemeter?

Comment: Jmeter is design for it, can you add more details so answers won't be opinion based?

Comment: it depends how complex and how realistic your user scenarios are... are you just testing where is the readline for each individual API call, or are you simulating 10k users with the full user flow (e.g. get all item IDs, go through few pages of items, sort by date or alphabetically, get item details for some IDs, modify few items, ...). You **should** be just fine hitting API endpoints individually. Whether you can simulate 10k user sessions with the API is another story.

Comment: @user7294900 - Yes I just added detail operations.

Comment: @diginoise - I have updated question with example operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about API you should be rather considering "requests per second" rather than "users" as I strongly doubt that end users will be sending requests to API endpoints via [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

No matter whether your goal is "users" or "requests per second" it is **only you** who can answer as it depends on many parameters like:

- your machine hardware specifications
- software specifications (OS/JVM/JMeter version and architecture)
- nature of your test (request/response size, number of [pre](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[post processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), etc)

So you should act as follows:

1. Make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure you monitor baseline health metrics of the node which is running JMeter (CPU, RAM, Swap, Network, Disk), you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for that .
3. Start with minimal load (1 virtual user or 1 request per second) and increase the load until your machine starts swapping or any other health metric exceeds, say, 80% of maximum available capacity. Once it happens take a look into active threads ([Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener) or throughput ([Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/)) - this is the maximum number of users or hits per second you can produce on particular this host for particular this test. If it is enough - you're good to go, if not - you will have to switch to [Distributed testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

See [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter) article for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The whole answer is an elaborate **it depends**.

The best thing you can do is to run **PerfMon** agents on the server generating the load as well as on the server running the system under test.

This way you should see (in the CPU utilization and free memory statistics) whether you had maxed what the server providing the API can do or whether it is your load generator running out of steam. In the first case you got some readline based on the hardware and configuration you had run with. In the second one you have an indication to employ more than 1 box to generate the load or to investigate settings and options.

Have a closer look at **[PerfMon JMeter plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)** for exact details.